# Почему может отсутствовать namespace? Отсутствует System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net

У меня почему нет `namespace System.Text.Json`. Почему так и как это исправить?

Comment: Оно появилось в .NET Core 3.0, а у вас что?

Comment: Для ранних версий можно попробовать добавить из NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Text.Json

Comment: @АндрейNOP, У меня .NET 4.0. Я пробовал, но выскакивает это: ``Не удалось установить пакет «System.Text.Json 4.7.0». Вы пытаетесь установить этот пакет в проект, требуемая версия платформы которого — «.NETFramework,Version=v4.0», но в пакете нет ссылок на сборки или файлов содержимого, совместимых с этой платформой. Дополнительную информацию можно получить у автора пакета.``    
`

Comment: А что заставляет вас сидеть на .Net 4.0?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, поддержка старых windows

Comment: @zodiak1 [Net Core 3.1 поддерживает Windows 7](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/3.1/3.1-supported-os.md)

Comment: @ГеннадийП, я за поддержку XP или Vista... Не помню уже

Comment: @zodiak1 А зачем их поддерживать такие древние ОС?

Comment: @ГеннадийП, там где будет использоваться приложение они могут встречаться

Comment: @zodiak1 Ну так бы сразу и сказали. Используйте Json.NET, у него есть поддержка 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать newtonsoft.json